# Limit the maximum size of a Gmail

Tags: java, android, email, gmail

Hello I'm new to working with Gmail in Android and I would like to know if it is possible to set the maximum size of the emails themselves.

**To clarify:** I am **not** trying to increase the maximum size limit, but rather set a smaller maximum limit for the company I work for. (15 MB instead of Google's 25 MB limit to be exact)

If anyone knows how to do this either programmatically or via device/app settings I would really appreciate it.

I have already read various articles and played around with the device I was given to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This does not sound like a problem that can be solved with code.